# How to make the second enumerate environment continue withe the same format?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

When I use the `enumerate` environment inside another `enumerate`, it change the format of listing from numbers to letters, all I want to do is to continue with numbers but with sub numbers like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the way the `enumerate` environment works using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `\setlist` functionality:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\theenumi.\arabic*.},ref={\theenumi.\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\theenumii.\arabic*.},ref={\theenumii.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item An item
    \item An item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item An item
      \item An item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item An item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item An item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\setlist[<list>,<level>]{<props>}` updates the list `<list>` at level `<level>` with the given `<props>`. Above I've updated levels `2` and `3` to prepend their hierarchical parent counter.

---

`enumitem`'s `label*` property provides a similar interface:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item An item
    \item An item
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
      \item An item
      \item An item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item An item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item An item
\end{enumerate}
```

In the first example above I've also set the `ref` property to remove the trailing `.` (if that's needed).

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to return to the old format in the same document how to dismiss this update?

Comment: @mostafax80: You can revert back to the default by adding `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={(\alph*)},ref={(\alph*)}} \setlist[enumerate,3]{label={\roman*.},ref={\roman*}}` anywhere in your code.